# Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT)modification

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, system-calls, interrupt-handling

In the flow of control in linux kernel, found that control moves to IDT which has the location of interrupts(ex: 0x80 system call). And then control moves to the appropriate System call. Also read that IDT is initialized at boot time only.

I would like to know more about the IDT information from a real kernel, like its location. Also like to know, wthether at any other time its being modified?

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing a rooktit, are we ?

Anyways, you can use the LIDT/SIDT x86 instructions to directly find and manipulate the IDT.
You can also find some information about IDT hooking on some good [phrack articles](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=inurl%3Aphrack.org+IDT&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ca05a7bb65e82229) about exactly this subject.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, the declarations for IRQ-handling functions can be found in [include/linux/interrupt.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/interrupt.h). Generic handling code can be found in [kernel/irq/](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/kernel/irq/), and platform specific code under the arch/ directories - take a look at eg, [arch/x86/kernel/irq.c](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/arch/x86/kernel/irq.c) and the other irq*.c files in that directory.

You should read the comments in the kernel/irc/*.c files to understand locking rules and mechanisms regarding IRQs in Linux. Note that other OSes can and will have different locking rules. Good luck!